# MVC form post doesn't return render partial result

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

According to some post here, i user Html.BeginFrom instead of Ajax.BeginForm, but on submit I take the control and return results with partial view:

```
$('#SearchForm').on('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post('/Search/Index', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        $('#searchResults').html(response); // assuming response is HTML
    });
});
```

Here is the action which i call:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchModel searchModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            searchModel = CustomBehaviour.GetResults(searchModel);
            return PartialView("SearchResults", searchModel);
        }

        return View(searchModel);
    }
```

When debugging the action is called and the js is called, also but there are no results, what could be the problem?

Here is the view:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal", id="SearchForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
             @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Requirement)

             @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Location)


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Base.Search</button>

        }               

<div id="#searchResults">
</div>
```

Comment: Is `ModelState.IsValid` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your div id:

```
<div id="#searchResults">
</div>
```

It needs to be:

```
<div id="searchResults">
</div>
```

Comment: omg how could i've missed that, and i've been struggling with this for long time!

Comment: I'll be honest, I set a test project up & couldn't quite see what was wrong for a bit. We get so used to seeing the jquery #id selector. :)